# Python QuickBooks API

Tags: python, django, api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have a problem working with python-quickbooks package, I try to follow the docs: https://pypi.org/project/python-quickbooks/

Here is my code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
from quickbooks import QuickBooks
from quickbooks.objects.account import Account

auth_client = AuthClient(
    client_id=settings.QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=settings.QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_SECRET,
    environment='sandbox',
    redirect_uri=settings.QUICKBOOKS_REDIRECT_URI,
)

client = QuickBooks(
    auth_client=auth_client,
    refresh_token=settings.QUICKBOOKS_REFRESH_TOKEN,
    company_id=settings.QUICKBOOKS_REALM_ID
)

account = Account()
account.from_json(
 {
  "AccountType": "Accounts Receivable",
  "Name": "MyJobs"
 }
)
account.save(qb=client)
```

However, this results in error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Everything looks like valid. Try to set breakpoint to see full response from QBO (not only serialized exception message).

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide ACCESS_TOKEN in AuthClient.

In order to get an access token, you have to pass authorization. You can check details about the authorization process here https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0-playground

Also here is a repo with an example of how to use AuthClient: https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleOAuth2_UsingPythonClient

```py
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
from quickbooks.client import QuickBooks, Environments
auth_client = AuthClient(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL, Environments.SANDBOX, ACCESS_TOKEN)

qbo_client = QuickBooks(
    auth_client=auth_client,
    refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN,
    company_id=REALM_ID,
)
```